# Evaluating Inverse Trigonometry Functions

Tags: trigonometry

Say we are given a problem such as $\arctan(\frac{\sqrt2}{2})=\theta$

Theta evaluates to $\frac{\pi}{4}\text{rad}$.

I know this only because I have it memorised.

What is an intuitive and procedural way to determine these values without relying solely on memorisation?

Say if instead it was $\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{14}}{145})=\theta$

How is this evaluated without use of unit circle memorisation?

Comment: Look up the table, use calculator. There's no easy way to calculate functions that do not boil down to finite polynomials. For this particular function you also can draw right triangles with certain sides and try to evaluate the angle somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following
$$\arctan x=y\implies x=\tan y \implies x=\frac{e^{iy}-e^{-iy}}{i\{e^{iy}+e^{-iy}\}}
\\ ix=\frac{e^{2iy}-1}{e^{2iy}+1}\implies ixe^{2iy}+ix=e^{2iy}-1\implies e^{2iy}=\frac{1+ix}{1-ix}
\\ y=\frac{1}{2i}\ln\frac{1+ix}{1-ix}$$

Comment: This answer lacks intuitive explanation.